# Rename portions of named list of lists without for loop

Tags: r, purrr

I have a list of lists like this

```
list1 <- list(a = 1, error = 2)
list2 <- list(a = 1, error = 3)
mylist <- list(list1, list2)
```

I'd like to rename all the elements currently named `"a"` to the names in `new_names`

```
new_names <- c("new_1", "new_2")
```

I can do this with a `for` loop like so

```
for(i in seq_along(mylist)) {
  names(mylist[[i]])[names(mylist[[i]]) == "a"] <-  new_names[i]}
```

and get my desired result:

```
mylist
[[1]]
[[1]]$new_1
[1] 1

[[1]]$error
[1] 2


[[2]]
[[2]]$new_2
[1] 3

[[2]]$error
[1] 4
```

I'd like to do this without the `for` loop.  Something like this `map` function perhaps, which doesn't work because it replaces all names, not just those that are `"a"`.

```
library(purrr)
mylist_2 <- map(mylist, ~{names(.)[names(.) == "a"] <-  new_names})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Map` from `baseR`

```
f <- function(x, y) {
  names(x)[names(x) == "a"] <- y
  x
}

Map(f, x = mylist, y = new_names)
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$new_1
#[1] 1
#
#[[1]]$error
#[1] 2
#
#
#[[2]]
#[[2]]$new_2
#[1] 1
#
#[[2]]$error
#[1] 3
```

---

Using `purrr` it would be `map2`

```
purrr::map2(mylist, new_names, f)
```